# How do you stop or prevent gitlab from running on startup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, gitlab

I've installed gitlab on Ubuntu 14.04, from the following deb file:

```
gitlab_6.9.2-omnibus-1_amd64.deb
```

It works beautifully. But I want to perform some maintenance on the box without gitlab running, and I can't find anyway to do this.

There is nothing in cron, nothing in /etc/init.d that I can see.

All the documentation points to /home/gitlab as the root folder, where in mine it's /var/opt/gitlab and some others.

I see it's running nginx, postgres & redis. I can kill the individual components, and hopefully that would be enough, but I'd rather it shutdown cleanly, or just not start. These components are not part of the /etc/init.d system ...

Any ideas?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35902817 for systemd based systems

Answer (score 18):

Found the answer. Most of the configuration appears to be in:

```
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc
```

Whose config.yml file mentions gitlab-ctl, which is available everywhere as a command:

```
gitlab-ctl stop
```

Stops gitlab fully.

Comment: But how do I stop it loading at startup?

Comment: These stay on after gitlab-ctl stop (how to kill>?)
runsv gitlab-workhorse & runsv gitlab-monitor

Answer (score 5):

To disable gitlab from autostarting in ubuntu 14.04

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.override
```

[how does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Comment: DANGER ZONE: this *permanently* corrupts your gitlab auto-startup.
See below answers on how to restore.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to reenable their gitlab autostart script and corrupted their 
startup script like I did.
This is the default config of **/etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.override**

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown
respawn
post-stop script
   # To avoid stomping on runsv's owned by a different runsvdir
   # process, kill any runsv process that has been orphaned, and is
   # now owned by init (process 1).
   pkill -HUP -P 1 runsv$
end script
exec /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start
```

Comment: Yes, this is the answere to re-enable it. Because after using the command mdma provided, you wont be able to re-enable gitlab because the default content of gitlab-runsvdir.override will be lost.
I had this issue by reading this answere

Answer (score 1):

This command shows cleaner

`$ sudo systemctl disable gitlab-runsvdir`

Answer (score 0):

For those who have /etc/inittab, check if it contains a line such as

```
CS:123456:respawn:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start
```

and comment this line.